# Add include directory with Visual Studios 16.6

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

So i need to add a include directory to my project but the properties page gui has changed and now only has 5 options and none of them appear to add a include directory. Anyone figured it out yet because I can't seem to find the option in their new project property's setup. I'm on a c++ project if it matters.

[image]

Comment: i think you need to open the property setup for the project not the entire solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have opened the properties page of the solution. You need to open the properties page of the project instead.

**Project** » Properties » C/C++ » General » Additional include directories